# Trying to find the same string in a text file using Python returns two different results

Tags: python

I have this text file called "testing.txt".
If I try to find a string in it using find() once it gives me the location. If I do it a second time it tells me the string isn't in the file. Here's the code (from shell):

```
>>> blast = open("testing.txt")
>>> blast.read().find("AC068207.60")
25
>>> blast.read().find("AC068207.60")
-1
```

Reloading blast with the first line of code resets this problem.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first read exhausts the file iterator, so that the second read returns an empty string, and find therefore returns -1.

You can seek to the start of the file, to read the file all over:

```
>>> blast.read().find("AC068207.60")
25
>>> blast.seek(0)
>>> blast.read().find("AC068207.60")
```

On a side note, do remember to `close` the file object.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please **accept** answers that solve your issue (press the check mark left of it).  You might only be able to do this after some time has passed to avoid rashness.  Btw, comments like "Thanks!" are generally discouraged to save space and reading time.